# Dynamic MVC Routing Removing Id With Efficient Database Lookup

Tags: sql-server, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, fluent-nhibernate, asp.net-mvc-routing

I have an MVC 3 application where I want dynamic Urls which do not contain a controller or key name. A good example of this would be if I had a blog, and users add in new posts.

Say a user creates a post called

**My Blog Post**

I have a method that creates a url SLUG and stores it in the database with the entry, so I want the Url to be

**/my-blog-post**

This has no controller or key name in the url now? How do I achieve this with MVC routing? Currently I'm doing it by matching the Url with an ID like **/my-blog-post_1234** and using that ID as the DB lookup key using fluent nhibernate but I'm a little lost once I remove the ID?

As I can still get the string/slug, but that means I now have to do a SQL lookup based on the string 'my-blog-post'? I have read this is not efficient and could compromise speed, and some of these titles could be pretty long.

I've heard people saying things about custom route tables? Would this help me or not? I suppose the main thing is getting the data from the database in the quickest most efficient way.

any help/pointers greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The MVC framework isn't going to provide any help here. Your requirement is to query by slug, so that's what you'll need to do in the DB.

You just need to make sure you have an index on this column in the DB to make sure the query doesn't need to do a table scan.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like what you really want is a document database. Coupled with MVC. I would highly recommend ravendb,